# How to print a word in Perl from a line which has matching letters

Tags: regex, perl, find

I am using a Perl to read a file and print a word located in 5th field.
Here is my line:

```
MN2 x=2 y=3 z=8 highway=9 industry=cotton price=40 unit=2
```

I am reading the line and printing the `highway=9`.
My issue is that sometimes the location of `highway=9` in the line changes and so I print a wrong data.

Is there any simple command in Perl which grabs the word "highway" and prints its value rather than printing based on the field number.

Comment: Can you please post the code that you have written?

Answer (score 3):

Use [regular expression](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

```
open my $fh, "<", "file.txt" or die "$! error opening ";
while (<$fh>)
{
    print $1 if( m/\b(highway=[^\s]+)\b/);
}
```

`\b` means boundary. which helps to match the word which contain the exact word `highway=22`. Without using `\b` it will matches the word between the character for example without boundary matches the following data `somehighway=221data`

`+` matches the previous character one or more times (greedy). In your script which is match the digit characters one or more times

`$1` stores the first grouping value from the pattern matching.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works as I was expecting. Sometime my data-format is highway=2.8e+10  and some time just 28 ...is there anyway to make it format independent ?

Answer (score 0):

`perl -pE 's/.*\bhighway=(\d+).*\b/$1/' < file.txt`

Comment: I don't know what is the use of substitution here.?